# How do I change code template triggering behavior in Netbeans 8.0?

Tags: java, javascript, php, templates, netbeans

I've run into an issue with code template triggering behavior in Netbeans 8.0. I recently upgraded from Netbeans 7.2 where this behavior wasn't present.

In Netbeans 8.0 code templates are being triggered when writing comments. This makes writing words such as 'for' or 'if' rather troublesome.

```
// This code does something if
```

Turns into this:

```
// This code does something if() {
}
```

Then, in a similar issue, code templates are **not** being triggered when in code highlighting mode.

[image]

Typing 'ap' should trigger a code template I've set up, but when in that highlighted context code templates do not trigger.

Is there any way to control the triggering behavior (such as enabling / disabling) of code templates in certain contexts in Netbeans 8.0? Thanks!